# make a WHILE contition while with a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, conditional-statements, long-integer

How could I do litteraly 1000 'or' conditions im my `while`, for image processing.

The goal here is to do this :

```
while (img0[i,j] != NOIR0).all() or (img0[i,j] != NOIR1) or (img0[i,j] != NOIR2) ... :
```

and this goes on to NOIR999, with NOIRx being different constants.
I thought to code a `for` that fulfil a string, but I can't put it as a condition in the while.

Could someone help me please ? :)

Comment: Please post code as text, not an image.

Comment: Please read about [ask] and how to provide a [mre]. Also, don't post images or links to images of stuff that can easily go as formatted text in your question. Please [edit] your question and copy-paste the code and then highlight it and press ctrl+k

Comment: @Tomerikoo good advice... but what is Ctrl+K doing?

Comment: @ArcoBast as my comment was implying, it formats the text as code

Comment: @Tomerikoo wow .. what a great function. was not aware of this.

Comment: You might be looking for the [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) function. Something like: `while all(x for n in range(1000)):` where `x` is your current condition in the `while`

Comment: Thanks for your advices, this is my first post so I am here also to learn to post. The post has been edited.

Answer (score 0):

for the n you can do this:

```
while n<=999:
    print(n)
    n = n+1
```

This is the most basic layout of a while loop.
A while loop continues on forever until a condition is met.

If you want a for loop:

```
for n in range(0, 1000):
    print(n)
```

Comment: Please only answer well-asked questions.

Comment: @Tomerikoo I submitted an edit to make the question more clear

Comment: How can you make the question more clear? It is something only the OP can do with the way the question is right now. It is completely not clear what his code is, what he is trying to acheive and how we can help him... Your answer is a nice attempt of teaching about loops in general, but I don't see how it relates to the question

Comment: @Tomerikoo It seems that he is familiar with everything except loops. I fixed his grammer and everything to make things more clear. I can't comment because my rep is under 50.

Comment: This is how it looks after my grammer edits:I am not currently an expert of Python, but I am working on it. How could I do exactly 1000 conditions for my while for a image processing? On the picture you can see the while, (v=locals()) and inside the condition, and n must go from 0 to 999. I thought to do for loop, but I can't get the right condition.
Could someone help me please ? :)

Comment: I am sorry but grammer fixes (usually) do not make a question on-topic. Putting language aside, this question is simply unclear in its essence, not in its wording. It is not clear what loops exactly the OP is looking for, what he is trying to do with them etc... These kind of issues can only be solved by the OP himself by providing more details in the question and better formatting it

Comment: I am sorry again, but I can't see how your "fixed" version is any clearer...

Comment: @Tomerikoo you're right, I'll delete my answer in exactly 45 minutes. Thanks for all the tips and suggestions!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210080/discussion-between-alex-liu-10101-and-tomerikoo).

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the built-in [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function.

This function receives an iterator and will return `True` if *any* of the items is evaluated to `True`, else it will return `False`.

The good thing with that is *short-circuiting* - whenever a `True` value is encountered, the function will not continue with the iterable.

```py
while any((img0[i, j] != f"NOIR{n}").all() for n in range(1000)):
```